# How to check if all columns in a dataframe contain timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timestamp

My data contains time like this 2015-04-01 12:15:12-07:00 and I want to loop over all rows in a column of a dataframe to check how many -07:00 there are.

```
new_list = []
for item in {"local_time", "basic_verification_local_time"}:
     dropped_data[item] = pd.to_datetime(dropped_data[item])
     if dropped_data[item].astype(str).str.isdigit('-07:00'):           
         new_list.append(item)

Output: TypeError: wrapper() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please add a sample of your data. Without a full reprex we will have a hard time to figure out the problem (see [reprex]). Please add a tag for the language you use so that experts can find your question.

Answer (score 0):

`-07:00` is a UTC offset - you can parse to datetime and check where the offset is -7 hours. Ex:

```
import pandas as pd
# some dummy data...
df = pd.DataFrame({'time': ["2015-04-01 12:15:12-07:00", "2015-04-01 13:15:12-07:00",
                            "2015-04-01 14:15:12-08:00", "2015-04-01 15:15:12-08:00"]})
# to datetime
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
# count occurances where UTC offset is -7 hours
print((df['time'].apply(lambda t: t.utcoffset()) == pd.Timedelta(hours=-7)).sum())
# 2
```